# How to refactor nested switch statements best?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, refactoring

ok so here is my problem.

basically a have a structure like this (regular table):

```
   | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 
----------------------
b1 | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4
----------------------
b2 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8
----------------------
b3 | v9 | vA | vB | vC
```

atm. the a-values are inside an enum (enumA), also the b-values (enumB)
a1 - a4 can be selected via a combobox that is bound to the enum, same for b1 - b3.

based on the selection of both I have specific values that are assigned to an aXbY combination and returned for further calculation.
these values are selected via a nested switch statement like this:

```
switch (enumA) {
   case a1:
       switch (enumB) {
           case b1: return v1;
           case b2: return v2;
```

and so on.

What I want to know is how to refactor my code best to improve code quality.
edit: I am looking for an object oriented solution!

Note: I don't expect a or b to grow at all. Yet, lets asume that I am in a situation where I do. Lets also asume that I expect enumA to grow more likely then enumB.

What I though about so far:

**Strategy Pattern hardcore all the way**

I could refactor every "ab" combination to its own type, that implements a common interface and every type returns the correct value.

pros:

- no nested blown up switch statement.
- open closed principle yay.

cons:

- seems like an overkill to have a type for every combination.
- I would lose the structure because I could theoretically have an a1b4 combination without the equivalent a2b4 and so on.

**Strategy Pattern for enumA, Exact Method for enumB**

I could refactor a1-aN to types, that all implement the same interface, which has the three methods getB1, getB2, getB3 that return the appropriate value.

pros:

- I can throw away the outer switch.
- I can enforce the table structure with the common interface.

cons:

- violation of open closed principle since I have to change the interface once a new b values comes in and also adjust every type with that interface.
- I still have the inner switch statement in order to evalueate which method to pick.

Are there better patterns for my situation? Is there a way to stay flexible while still enforcing the table structure? If I use types, instead of enums, how to make the transition to the UI? Use reflection to get every class that implements a certain interface and show the name (or whatever property) in the combobox?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a table structure, I would place all `v` values inside a multidimensional array:
 `vType[,] multiArray = new vType[aLength, bLength];`

Because all enums have an integer for their base value (`int` by default), you can cast the selected enum to an integer. enumA would give you the column index and enumB the row index. Now you can return `v` in a single line of code:

```
return multiArray[(int)enumA, (int)enumB];
```

No switch cases, no interfaces, no seperate types. If `a or b` grows, then you don't have to change your code at all (pretty much)...

Comment: thank you for your answer but I was looking for an object oriented approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather prefer using a Dictionary than Switch-case here, where Key would be combination of 'enumA' and 'enumB', and value would be v1 (v2, v3...)

```
public class CombinedKey {
  private enumA _enumAValue;
  private enumB _enumBValue;

  override Equals..
  override GetHashCode..

}

public class MainProgram {
   private Dictionary<CombinedKey,SomeValue> _combinedKey2Value = new Dictionary<CombinedKey,SomeValue);

   /// Populate this dictionary based on your Switch-case logic

   public bool TryGetValue(enumA enumAValue, enumB enumBValue, out SomeValue someValue){
          var combinedKey = new CombinedKey(enumAValue, enumBValue);
          return _combinedKey2Valye.TryGetValue(combinedKey, out someValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I was looking for an object oriented approach to this problem.